# Swing app freezes in dual screen windows 7 environment when moving app to top right hand corner of second monitor

Tags: java, swing

I built this Swing app to help my girlfriend get a particular job done faster. On my dual monitor windows system, the app and the Operating System freeze when moving the app to the extreme right hand side of the second monitor. Windows recovers, but the app does not. Has anyone experienced this sort of issue and know how to solve it? Below is the github link to the source code.

I tried to also provide a screenshot of the frozen app and the OS but it is difficult to take one when the OS freezes.

The app works fine on her Mac.

https://github.com/johndeverall/BehaviourCoder

Comment: I do not get this behavior, at least not running the app from within eclipse.  My second monitor is placed to the right of the main one (the main is a laptop screen), and I put it to the right put it all the way to the right, put it to the right and had windows create a right-hand-half-screen of it, no problem.  I''m running Win 7 64-bit, Java 7.  Can you think of something else that might be a necessary condition?  It does not appear to be in your code, at least not in the source as distributed.

Comment: I've been reading this link, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java2d-142140.html from 3.1.3 onwards but have yet to try anything suggested. My hardware should be ok. Thinkpad W530. In every other respect your environment sounds the same as mine. At least that gives me confidence it should work for her on the windows machines in her office. Thanks.

Comment: Could you start a Task Manager and at least see if the CPU is executing some kind of loop, and in what process?  That might be interesting, and doesn't take much time (aside from the reboot...)

Comment: Same problem with a simple example Netbeans Swing app.

Comment: I could solve my problem with that: https://www.drastic.tv/support-59/supporttipstechnical/66-javaondualmonitors

Comment: Thank you @Gustave and Arcy. This app will be used again for more publications, and accordingly I will be making more modifications to the code on the same laptop, so I'll give your suggestions a go in the next few months when I start working on the code base again :)

Comment: Related (possible resurgence 2 years later): [Application Display Issues After Windows Update August 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45710630/3357935)

Comment: I just got the same problem with Oracle SQL Developer (both the 4.0.3 version I used previously and the 17.4.0.355 I installed to try to solve the issue) and running with Java 1.8.0_144.