# Display issues on multiple screens after Windows 7 Update KB4034664 (August 2017)

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, multiple-monitors

Users of our application have been experiencing problems with their Swing GUIs not drawing correctly.

The common link between all users with problems is that they've recently applied a Windows update. Users have reported that dialogs draw correctly on some monitors but not on others.

An example of the *kind* of problems we're seeing*:

[image: Application draw issues]

Users also report dialogs which only show a frame, and are otherwise transparent. Effectively the same kind of problems you'd see if the UI thread were blocked.

What could be the problem?

---

*I can't post screenshots of our actual application as it contains sensitive information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** This issue has been fixed in update [KB4039884](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4039884/windows-7-update-kb4039884).

---

This seems to be a reasonably wide-spread issue caused by a recent patch. It's not limited to Java:

> It seems, that Microsoft’s Update [KB4034664](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/4034664) (and [KB4034679](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/4034679)) for
>   Windows 7 and Windows Server is causing display issues with several
>   applications on a second screen.

Reported by [Born City](http://borncity.com/win/2017/08/12/windows-update-kb4034664-is-causing-trouble-on-2nd-screen/#more-3478), [Computer World](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3215194/microsoft-windows/two-of-this-months-win7-patches-causing-second-screen-problems.html), and [Microsoft themselves](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4034664/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-kb4034664):

> If a machine has more than one monitor connected and the screen
>   numbering is not in sequence, some applications will experience
>   rendering issues.

You should be able to solve the problem by rolling back the patch. It is a security update (links above detail what is included), so if you're particularly risk-averse you may not want to do this.

**Microsoft lists the workaround as:**

> 1. Enable Desktop Composition (needs graphics card support).
> 2. Make sure that the main monitor is on the top left in the monitor layout.

[image: Example of suggested monitor layout]

You could also try switching to a single monitor setup, or making other changes to your monitor configuration (Control Panel > Display > Change display settings). Some reports speculate that which monitor is set as your 'main display' may make a difference.

You might also want to try the following flag: `-Dsun.noddraw=true`

Comment: I can confirm that changing the monitor layout resolved the issue for Kronos Workforce Central. (Java-based web application)

Comment: [According to neunbeere.de](https://www.neunbeere.de/blog/2017/08/graphics-bug-in-windows-7-after-installing-august-2017-security-updates/) "*The actual problem seems to be within the Windows API Function “StretchDIBits”. After the security update, **when this function is used to draw graphics onto a part of the screen with negative screen coordinates, it fails***"